# UUIDs as object keys in JSON Schema

Tags: json, jsonschema

I am trying to define a JSON Schema for a JSON API that uses UUIDs as their key for a JSON object. What makes it more complex is that it is also a nested object.
Example:

```
{
   "nodes": {
       "7059e5ad-fac0-4fda-aa3e-2655d6e60506": {
           "type": "Class",
           "name": "Supermarket",
           "data": {},
           "instances": {},
       }
   }
}
```

Which has a generated schema like this:

```
 {
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "nodes": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "7059e5ad-fac0-4fda-aa3e-2655d6e60506": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                        "type": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "name": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "data": {
                            "type": "object"
                        },
                        "instances": {
                            "type": "object"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way I can make a schema where there are no UUIDs values in the schema because these values can be anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leverage the existing uuid format definition, in draft2019-09 and later:

```
"propertyNames": {
  "format": "uuid"
},
"additionalProperties": {
  .. definition of the values that go under the uuid properties ..
}
```

Comment: This won't work in draft-04, which is the dialect used in the question.

Comment: @Relequestual yes, I did specify the version limitation in my response.  It's best if answers are useful to a broader audience than just the one person asking the question, or we get similar questions asked all the time.

Comment: Good point! The Op did not state they are unable to change versions.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `properties` with `patternProperties`, and your UUID with the following regular expression.

`^[0-9a-fA-F]{8}\b-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\b-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\b-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\b-[0-9a-fA-F]{12}$`

The `patternProperties` keyword is like the `properties` keyword, but you can use a regular expression for the key. This works in [draft-04 JSON Schema](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-fge-json-schema-validation-00#section-5.4.4), but it's highly recommended to use a newer version of JSON Schema if you can.

This regex was [borrowed](https://ihateregex.io/expr/uuid/), but I'm reasonably confident it is for a UUID.

Comment: Thank you for your insight on the difference with the newer version, I will use that one and implement @Ether's solution.